# How to do multiple plots reactively in R?

Tags: r, shiny, reactive-programming

New to reactive in R. Trying to reactivefileread a csv, then generate 3 plots upon given input range for filtering.

I have tried adding it to be reactive, calling the reactivefilereader data() for each ggplot again. I am confused about how to layer these lines of code so that it can be reactive file read in, take the input range and filter, then feed this back to the renderplot/ggplot for each. I can get 1 plot fine, but trying to do all 3 I only get the last plot. Then if I change stuff, I usually get recursive or reactive errors, or I manage to get all 3 plots but lose reactivity in regards to date input changes.

This is the code I have that does react to date changes, but manages to only plot the last plot.

the csv file looks like so:

```
    temp_h       humidity      pressure        pitch         roll           yaw          mag_x          mag_y          mag_z        accel_x       accel_y        accel_z     gyro_x   gyro_y   gyro_z     timestamp     
 ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- ------------- -------------- -------------- ------------- ------------- -------------- ------------- -------- -------- -------- ---------------- 
  36.93448639   33.67306137             0   2.052537159   344.9172962   189.5288875   -24.15678406   -2.991427183   26.07371902   0.000484892   -0.262453765   0.948711813   ['x']    ['y']    ['z']    5/9/2019 11:57  
  37.00978851   34.73247528   1002.021484   359.9863889    343.752597    190.284607    -66.8992157    -8.57483387   71.15454865             0   -0.281751841   0.966257989   ['x']    ['y']    ['z']    5/9/2019 11:58
```

.app file

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Growth Chamber 109"),


    column(4, wellPanel(
        dateRangeInput(
            'dateRange',
            label = 'Filter results by date',
            start = as.Date('2019-01-01') ,
            end = NULL
                     )
    )),


    plotOutput("temp"),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.16/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js",
                    type = "text/javascript")
    ),
    HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>')





)


#The reactive file reader reads in the Raspberry Pi Python generated file SenseLog.csv and returns as data()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactiveFileReader(
        intervalMillis = 5000,
        session = session,
        filePath = "SenseLog.csv",
        readFunc = read.csv)


    #Server call for rendering the plot output
    output$temp <- renderPlot({
        plot(data())


        #Change the function output data() to gc109. Reactive expressions/functions and the () mess me up sometimes
        gc109 <- data()



        #Parse time out  in proper format
        gc109$timestamp <-
            strptime(gc109$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


        #Filter data from logger based on date range input from session
        try1 <- subset(gc109, timestamp >= input$dateRange[1])
        try2 <- subset(try1, timestamp <= input$dateRange[2])


        #Fix column header names
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "timestamp"] <- "Date"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "temp_h"] <- "Temperature"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "humidity"] <- "Humidity"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "pressure"] <- "Pressure"


        #Fix dates/maintain time to plot properly
        try2$Date <- as.POSIXct(try2$Date)


        #Generate temperature plot

        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Temperature), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Humidity), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Pressure), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))
        })


}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Either return 3 different reactive plot objects or put 3 plots into one (maybe using cowplot package) then return 1 plot. At the moment, your `output$temp <- renderPlot({... `  will only return the last plot.

Comment: Regarding performance you might want to have a look at shiny's [plot caching](https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/plot-caching.html) capabilities.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks but I do hope to find a more elegant way - I just am worried about efficiency and wish i knew how to call 3 plots from 1 data processing event. This is what I settled with and it seems to be sufficient.

```
#
# This is a Shiny web application. You can run the application by clicking
# the 'Run App' button above.
#
# Find out more about building applications with Shiny here:
#
#    http://shiny.rstudio.com/
#

library(shiny)
library(tools)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
theme_set(theme_bw())

ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Growth Chamber 109"),


    column(4, wellPanel(
        dateRangeInput(
            'dateRange',
            label = 'Filter results by date',
            start = as.Date('2019-05-10') ,
            end = NULL
        )
    )),


    plotOutput("Temperature"),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.16/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js",
                    type = "text/javascript")
    ),
    HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>'),

    plotOutput("Humidity"),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.16/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js",
                    type = "text/javascript")
    ),
    HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>'),

    plotOutput("Pressure"),
    tags$head(
        tags$script(src = "https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/iframe-resizer/3.5.16/iframeResizer.contentWindow.min.js",
                    type = "text/javascript")
    ),
    HTML('<div data-iframe-height></div>')





)


#The reactive file reader reads in the Raspberry Pi Python generated file SenseLog.csv and returns as data()
server <- function(input, output, session) {
    data <- reactiveFileReader(
        intervalMillis = 5000,
        session = session,
        filePath = "SenseLog.csv",
        readFunc = read.csv)


    #Server call for rendering the temperature plot
    output$Temperature <- renderPlot({


        #Change the function output data() to gc109. Reactive expressions/functions and the () mess me up sometimes
        gc109 <- data()



        #Parse time out  in proper format
        gc109$timestamp <- strptime(gc109$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


        #Filter data from logger based on date range input from session
        try1 <- subset(gc109, timestamp >= input$dateRange[1])
        try2 <- subset(try1, timestamp <= input$dateRange[2])


        #Fix column header names
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "timestamp"] <- "Date"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "temp_h"] <- "Temperature"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "humidity"] <- "Humidity"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "pressure"] <- "Pressure"


        #Fix dates/maintain time to plot properly
        try2$Date <- as.POSIXct(try2$Date)


        #Generate temperature plot

        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Temperature), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

    })



    data <- reactiveFileReader(
        intervalMillis = 5000,
        session = session,
        filePath = "SenseLog.csv",
        readFunc = read.csv)


    #Server call for rendering the humidity plot
    output$Humidity <- renderPlot({


        #Change the function output data() to gc109. Reactive expressions/functions and the () mess me up sometimes
        gc109 <- data()



        #Parse time out  in proper format
        gc109$timestamp <- strptime(gc109$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


        #Filter data from logger based on date range input from session
        try1 <- subset(gc109, timestamp >= input$dateRange[1])
        try2 <- subset(try1, timestamp <= input$dateRange[2])


        #Fix column header names
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "timestamp"] <- "Date"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "temp_h"] <- "Temperature"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "humidity"] <- "Humidity"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "pressure"] <- "Pressure"


        #Fix dates/maintain time to plot properly
        try2$Date <- as.POSIXct(try2$Date)


        #Generate temperature plot

        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Humidity), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

    })

    data <- reactiveFileReader(
        intervalMillis = 5000,
        session = session,
        filePath = "SenseLog.csv",
        readFunc = read.csv)


    #Server call for rendering the pressure plot
    output$Pressure <- renderPlot({


        #Change the function output data() to gc109. Reactive expressions/functions and the () mess me up sometimes
        gc109 <- data()



        #Parse time out  in proper format
        gc109$timestamp <- strptime(gc109$timestamp, "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")


        #Filter data from logger based on date range input from session
        try1 <- subset(gc109, timestamp >= input$dateRange[1])
        try2 <- subset(try1, timestamp <= input$dateRange[2])


        #Fix column header names
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "timestamp"] <- "Date"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "temp_h"] <- "Temperature"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "humidity"] <- "Humidity"
        colnames(try2)[colnames(try1) == "pressure"] <- "Pressure"


        #Fix dates/maintain time to plot properly
        try2$Date <- as.POSIXct(try2$Date)


        #Generate temperature plot

        ggplot(aes(x = Date, y = Pressure), data = try2) + geom_point() +
            theme(text = element_text(size = 20))

    })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Would love a more efficient solution. The first two plots overlay in a weird fashion also.  Also on using raspberry pi to push via rsconnect, error code 1 but most likely a path issue.